# My SKLabelNode doesn't change color

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uicolor

I have an SKLabelNode in my iOS app to display a player's score.  I want to be able to change the color of it (for now, just to a standard cyan color).  But I can't seem to figure out why it's not changing.  I have another app where I've used this and had no issues at all.

```
SKLabelNode *pScoreNode;

NSString *playerScoreTracker;

- (SKLabelNode *)playerScoreNode
{
    pScoreNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"NEONCLUBMUSIC"];

    playerScoreTracker = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"POWER: %ld",(long)player_score];

    pScoreNode.text = playerScoreTracker;
    pScoreNode.fontSize = 20;
    pScoreNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),inBoundsOffset/3);
    pScoreNode.color = [SKColor cyanColor];

    pScoreNode.name = @"player1ScoreNode";

    return pScoreNode;
}
```

Then later in the update, I update the string with the updated score on each update.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    pScoreNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"POWER: %ld",(long)player_score];


}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe you want to use `pScoreNode.fontColor = [UIColor cyanColor];`.

The `color` property is for color blending in conjunction with `colorBlendFactor`.

Answer (score 12):

FYI, for those of you doing this in Swift use:

```
label.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Answer (score 3):

For example if u want to make your label black use;

```
label.color = [SKColor blackColor];
label.colorBlendFactor = 1;
```